# Django - Updated multiple models in single table form

Tags: python, django

I have four models:

[Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g70Da.png)

The models are connected via a foreign key of stg_location_param_id. Is there a way to have a tabular form (similar to excel) with the following:

[Desired Model Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bacZ2.png)

I'd like to have 1 form where the wRVU_amount, wRVU_rate, and rev_amount fields can be updated and saved at once. So it's updating multiple fields of multiple objects in multiple models as once. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0):

I need you to explain more detail about what you try to do.
Whether you try to update data to three models at the same time or you try to update three models when some event happen on another model that shared the same foreign key to the three models.

Comment: I went ahead and made the ask more explicit

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't update all the field at once because they are belong to different models.
You need to create instance of every object where the field belongs to separately and update them using those instance.